# TestLink xmlrpc API (via Python) 404 not found

Tags: python, xml-rpc, testlink

I'm trying to connect to TestLink via the xmlrpc API. I've set the following in TestLink's config.inc.php:

```
$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;
$tlCfg->exec_cfg->enabled_test_automation = ENABLED;
```

and restarted the apache sever. I tried to connect the TestLink server via the python package TestLink-API-Python-client (https://github.com/orenault/TestLink-API-Python-client)

```
from testlink import TestlinkAPIClient, TestLinkHelper
import sys

URL = 'http://MYSERVER/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc.php'
DevKey = 'MYKEY'

tl_helper = TestLinkHelper()
myTestLink = tl_helper.connect(TestlinkAPIClient) 
myTestLink.__init__(URL, DEVKEY)

myTestLink.checkDevKey()
```

And then I receive a TLConnectionError, stating my url, and 404 Not Found...

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: have you solved this? I am facing exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve it.

I reverted to working on the TestLink DB directly. I'm sure it's more fragile than using the API, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for help, this code worked for me:

`set TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_SERVER_URL=http://[YOURSERVER]/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php
set TESTLINK_API_PYTHON_DEVKEY=[Users devKey generated by TestLink]
python
import testlink
tls = testlink.TestLinkHelper().connect(testlink.TestlinkAPIClient)
tls.countProjects()`

Check out [TestLink API Documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/TestLink-API-Python-client/0.4.7) to learn more

Answer (score 0):

In a glance your XML-RPC URL seems wrong. It should be

```
http://YOURSERVER/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php
```